# erro ao iniciar react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

estou tentando rodar um projeto React-native pela depuração USB no celular e está dando erro. Saliento que já usei o 'adb devices~ e aparece o ID do meu celular no terminal, porem ao dar o comando 'yarn react-native run-android~ apresenta o seguinte erro:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/luan/Desktop/omnistack8/tindev/android/local.properties'.

Essa sdk local com os arquivos do Android Nativo pelo que eu entendo de React-Native deveriam ja vir configuradas, quais variaveis eu teria que adicionar nessa local.properties?

Comment: Você configurou as variáveis de ambiente?

Comment: Eu não tinha configurado corretamente pelo que eu vi, eu refiz tudo com mais calma e agora deu outro erro ao tentar rodar no android * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/caminho-do-sdk/android-sdk' does not exist.

Comment: Pela descrição do erro, ele não achou a pasta que você informou. Veja se este passo a passo te ajuda https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/android/linux

Answer (score 1):

Você chegou a configurar as variáveis de ambiente para o usuário ou para a máquina/sistema?

Te passaram um link que explica como definir as variáveis de ambiente:

1. `ANDROID_HOME` que por padrão fica em `%LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk` *(após instalação do Android Studio selecionando o Android SDK)*
2. na variável `%Path%` de sistema, não de usuário, você tem de adicionar os seguintes dirs:

   - `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`
   - `%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator`
   - `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools`
   - `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin`

Answer (score -2):

Pasta Android/local.properties/ colocar o diretório aonde tá instalado o SDK do android

meu caso os sdk ta instalado na pasta sdk.dir=/Users/joaodematejr/Library/Android/sdk